# error with bash script using rsync to copy directory with space in directory name

Tags: bash, shell

I've been trying all morning to get this to work, but can't find a fix. I'm trying to make a bash script rsync backup a copy of a directory. I keep running into a problems linked to species in the directory name. I can't seem to apply or find any previous fix to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Raj (Newbie)

I think the issue is getting the space in the directory name "Application Support" to be accepted by the script.

Thank you in advance.

Here's the bash script:

```
!/bin/bash

backuptodirectory=/Volumes/Backup/date/
directorytocopy=/Users/myname/Library/Application Support

if [ ! -d "$directorytocopy" ]; then
    echo "Source path: $directorytocopy doesn't exist"
    exit 1
fi
mkdir -p "$backuptodirectory"
echo copying $directorytocopy
rsync -progress $directorytocopy $backuptodirectory
```

Comment: use correct quotation around your variable names (i.e. `"$backuptodirectory"`)

Comment: Thank you Aserre. That's fixed it. Much appreciated. I also changed: directorytocopy=/Users/raj/Library/Application\ Support

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this is the changed script (which now works). Thank you Aserre.

```
!/bin/bash

backuptodirectory=/Volumes/Backup/date/
directorytocopy=/Users/myname/Library/Application\ Support

if [ ! -d "$directorytocopy" ]; then
    echo "Source path: $directorytocopy doesn't exist"
    exit 1
fi
mkdir -p "$backuptodirectory"
echo copying $directorytocopy
rsync -progress "$directorytocopy" "$backuptodirectory"
```